# windows:how to convert given number of txt file rows into EXCEL columns and repeat the process

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion

I have a txt file as the following

```
NAME1
COUNTRY1
ID1
NAME2
COUNTRY2
ID2
.
.
.
.
```

I would like to convert this pattern of one column txt file rows into the following pattern in EXCEL:

```
NAME1 COUNTRY1 ID1
NAME2 COUNTRY2 ID2
 .       .      .
 .       .      . 
 .       .      .
 .       .      .
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Input all the data into column **A**.  Then in **B1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROW()-1)*3,0)
```

Copy this cell across two columns and then downwards.

[image]